# Nagios log check plugin that doesn't use diff

Tags: monitoring, logging, nagios

we are using check_log from the nagios-plugins to monitor logs, but the problem is that with big logfiles, even if we rotate logs hourly, the plugin causes significant spikes in memory and cpu usage.

That is because check_log is using diff to compare an old version of the log file with the current one.

Question is, without having to check the source of all check_log alternatives, is there any that doesn't use diff but for example follows the last checked linenumber and picks up checking from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[check_logfiles](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Log-Files/check_logfiles/details) plugin is what you're looking for:

> When such a logfile rotation takes place, check_logfiles detects this
>   and analyses the lines of the archived logfile, even if it's
>   compressed.

Comment: Exaclty what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Checking log files on a scheduled basis is not a very efficient approach. While it would be posible to write a plugin which would would keep track of the position of the last offset in the file and handle rotations, a much simpler approach would be to run a filter daemon against the log files - there's [lots of such tools](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/links.html) available.

(you can still process the output of such tools using nagios for reporting / tracking purposes)

Comment: Imho running a daemon which prepares output for Nagios would add another layer of complexity (which also would need to be monitored).